# Плохое качество фотографии с камеры

Tags: java, android, камера

Я использую камеру и хочу работать с фотографией которая была сделана камерой. Но фотография получается очень плохого качества, подскажите как сделать получше качество. Мой код:

```
itmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

FileOutputStream fo;
try {
    destination.createNewFile();
    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
```

Сюда сохраняется не оригинал фотографии, а Thumbnail, что означает уменьшенный образец. А все потому, что целую фотографию (например 5 mb.) невозможно вместить в интент. Поэтому в него кладется такая маленькая превьюшка, и ссылка, по которой можно достать оригинал. Делать надо так:

```
    //Задаем путь, по которому надо сохранить полное изображение:        

    File newfile = new File(path);
    try { 
        newfile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {}       

    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    //Запускаем камеру
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

Дальше, в `onActivityResult` изображение считываем из файла

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Больше [тут](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20take%20photo%20front%20camera%20programmatically&es_th=1)